# Double log out is confusing UX design

Tags: feature-request, design, user-experience, logout

I find it counter-intuitive that the "log out" link leads to another page where you have the option to actually log out, e.g.

> [image]

I believe it would improve the user interface and therefore the user's experience to say, e.g. "log out of Stack Exchange on this device" and then actually do that. Even shorter would be "log out all".

Comment: Which bit's the confusing part? If it's the navigating to another page... then I hard disagree, it's just a confirmation screen, what if somebody accidentally clicked the "log out" link? I'd certainly hope it didn't log them out without question

Comment: @Nick Not that it really matters, but that "log out" doesn't actually log you out; I think it goes against the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: I am not astonished at all that "log out" takes me to another page. I routinely click on links labeled "check out" that take me to another page -- no astonishment there. I click on links labeled "log in" that take me to another page -- no astonishment there. I've even clicked on links labeled "check in" that take me to another page and was not astonished in the least. Not sure why this one combination of "log" and "out" causes so much astonishment. :)

Comment: I find it, not _astonishing_ but _oh yes, Stack Overflow is weird like that_. Github, Facebook, Google, Ebay, _etc_, do not have a "are you sure" page. I think it's to remind users that you are logging out of all your accounts, but I've always thought it's kind of awkward.

Comment: @Nick It's not necessary to have confirmation pages for non-destructive actions. If someone accidentally clicked the "log out" link, then they could just log back in again.

Comment: @CodyGray Sure it's not necessary, but it's certainly not confusing

Comment: I like the confirmation (and informing the user that they will be logging out of all sites, _and_ giving the option to log out on all devices without having to look for that option in settings). That said, a pop-up view that is easily dismissable with `Esc` would be much better (with the dedicated view used as a fallback).